# Can’t get HealthStore authorization on WatchOS 2 Beta 3 on the device

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit, watchos-2

I cannot access HealthStore, “requestAuthorizationToShareTypes” returns false on apple watch. No promt on the device pops up. 
But it works on the simulator.

Here is the code accessing the HealthStore

```
    healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: dataTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in

        if success != true {//returns false
            self.label.setText("not allowed")
        }
    }
```

I’m using xCode 7.0 Beta 3, WatchOS 2 Beta 3

I have red 
[Can't access HealthKit on watchOS 2 Beta 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357848/cant-access-healthkit-on-watchos-2-beta-3)
but the problem is different. I have no errors on the console.

Update.
After updating to the latest Beta 4 (xCode, iPhone app and watch os) the watch app don’t even load up. The wheel is just spinning. The app loads in simulator.

Comment: You should file a bug with Apple.

Comment: i am facing same issues...can you please give me solution if you found it?

Comment: Recently when i updated my iphone5 to 9.0 beta 5 then its not even installing the app

Comment: Unfortunately no, Each beta version gives different surprises. I think the best way is to wait for GM